# How to smooth object imported from AutoCAD?

Tags: import, obj, smooth

I have been modelling this product and the surface seems to be irregular. I have tried multiple methods to smooth en this but not successful yet

I have imported this file from Autocad as a .obj file. Hence, the model is irregular from the beginning itself. The shade smooth option does not seem to work. I have tried numerous other ways but have been unsuccessful till now.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: Honestly, changing CAD files into normal and usable mesh is quite a challenge, you can try to find some remeshers that have option to keep edges and crease, Doing this by hand would take you longer than original author made that cad version

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It depends on how the object is modelled in CAD software. Are you using Nurbs or polygonal modelling ?